# Windows Phone 7 - Capture Screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to capture the screen whilst my windows mobile application is running. I have this so far but I keep getting an ArgumentException of `The parameter is incorrect`. What am I doing wrong?

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);

wb.Render(this, null);

wb.Invalidate();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

int h = 212;

int w = 444;

wb.SaveJpeg(ms, w, h, 0, 100); // The parameter is incorrect

BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);

image1.Source = bitmapImage;
```

The above is within my MainPage constructor.

### Update

I managed to make use the great tutorial suggested by Matt.

However, it doesn't seem to capture anything from the `WebBrowser`.

1) Does anyone know how the native email application renders HTML email - what component does it use?

2) What is used to create the native applications in the Windows Phone 7 series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another solution just published by Jeff Wilcox

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/10/screenshots-cs-how-to-capture-screenshots-of-your-app-on-your-device/

It captures screenshots at intervals you specify and then saves them to IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Thanks this worked even better. One problem though, do you know any other methods which can capture the contents of a `webBrowser` element as everything I've tried gives me a blank rectangle.

Comment: The WebBrowser control isn't a Silverlight control and so can't be captured in this way. I think the only way to capture that is to get a screenshot via the emulator

Comment: How would I get a screenshot via the emulator? Would this still involve doing it via the application code? Any links?

Comment: @Abs either use the emulator tool or just take a screenshot on the PC running the emulator and clip as necessary

Comment: To be honest, I'm looking for a code based solution. One random question: the native email app in the windows phone, does it use the `WebBrowser` element to show HTML emails?

Comment: @Abs the native apps aren't written in Silverlight so I strongly doubt it. It also doesn't behave like a WebBrowser control.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you know what are they written and can we ever create native applications such as the email client - especially how it renders HTML emails?

Comment: @Abs [Apparently] The native apps were written before the Silverlight tools were originally available and so had to be written in something else. No details of development in non-managed code have been released or shown on any public roadmap. have you tried using RichTextBox to display richer content?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on first inspection. The SaveJpeg params look okay, but not sure about the [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)..

Check here for a code example:

http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/12/28/taking-a-screenshot-from-within-a-silverlight-wp7-application.aspx

Comment: The code in the link supplied seems to pass in an element and null to `WriteableBitmap`but it can only accept two ints in the dpcs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx