# Can we programmaticllay take screen shots using Blackberry and Windows 7 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, blackberry, screenshot

I  know that we can take screen shot of an App during runtime. In iOS we can use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to get the screen shot. We can also do the same in Android.

But is it possible with Blackberry and Windows 7 Mobile OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking screenshot of the current screen in BlackBerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891618/taking-screenshot-of-the-current-screen-in-blackberry)

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742591/windows-phone-7-capture-screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple search for "blackberry screenshot" on stackoverflow returned this pretty straightforward answer:
[Taking screenshot of the current screen in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891618/taking-screenshot-of-the-current-screen-in-blackberry)

And a search for "windows-phone screenshot" yields this:
[Windows Phone 7 - Capture Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742591/windows-phone-7-capture-screen)

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is for capture a screenshot of your own Windows Phone app, then [this post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/10/screenshots-cs-how-to-capture-screenshots-of-your-app-on-your-device/) from Jeff Wilcox will come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a function for that in Display. Check out the [SDK reference](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Homebrew tools you can use to take screenshots on WP7 [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20111023/homebrew-screenshot-tool-for-windows-phone-7-5-works-for-all-phones/) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1436742) however you wont be able to use these programatically. You can also something along the lines of [Mark Artega](http://blog.markarteaga.com/ScreenCaptureOnWindowsPhone7.aspx) or [Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/10/screenshots-cs-how-to-capture-screenshots-of-your-app-on-your-device/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no [Silverlight VisualBrush support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) for WP7 and no global Screenshot functionality on WP7 Mango, but [writablebitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
There is a very usefull way by using [default Microsoft Emulator integrated WP7](http://wmpoweruser.com/for-developers-windows-phone-7-emulator-screenshot-tool/) Screenshot Tool 
or use [third party methods](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/3-ways-to-take-screenshots-on-windows-phone-7-how-to/).

If you are familar with XNA Framework, there you can access to the screen. Using Multithreading, you can do your screenshots [that way](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows_phone/developing-for-windows-phone-7-wp7-screen-capture-allows-you-to-show-off-your-work/). If never used the last app because I feel fine using Microsofts Emulator Screenshot button to save my png images.

After you can stitch it [together](http://timoboehme.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/wp7-panorama-prototyping/) using different ways.
[image]